# Fibonacci numbers assignment but no clue of the meaning by sentence 1 and 2

Tags: education, fibonacci-numbers

[image]

my friend and I have no clue to solve the mentioned strategy

a and b must have to be equal to 1 because of the definition of fibonacci.
And we is thinking it has to do something about of:
$X_{n}= r_{1}+r_{2}$

Comment: As is says :" We will now look at a more common problem" (perhaps "general" instead of "common") ... So the point is to not only look at $x_n = x_{n-1}+ x_{n-2}$ but also $x_n = 2x_{n-1}+ 3x_{n-2}$  or $x_n = x_{n-1}+ 2x_{n-2} + 3x_{n-3}$  or anything similar. So we leave the Fibonacci behind.

Comment: Yep general.  We are thinking that 
$$r_1^{n-1}=r_1^{n-2}+r_1^{n-3}$$
$$0=r_1^{n-1}-r_1^{n-2}-r_1^{n-3}=r_1^{n-3}\cdot(r_1^{2}-r_1^{1}-1)$$ 
so if r1 is not equal to zero then r_1^{2}-r_1^{1}-1 must be equal to zero.  Because it is a second degree equation  then we can solve it with $$r_1=\frac{-(-1)+-\sqrt{(-1)^2-4\cdot 1\cdot -1}}{2\cdot 1}=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Comment: then $r_1=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and  $r_2=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

but how can we find the value of c1 and c2 .

Comment: Remember, you want to get $\,F_n=x_n\,$ so what does that mean for $n=1$ and $n=2$?

Comment: @Somos can you help at little more because we are pretty lost

Comment: The answer is in equation (1.31). What more do you need to know?

Comment: so we just say the constant $$c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$$ 


and then 

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{1}$$
 for m=1...n. But I thought that I should calculate the value for c not pick on

Answer (score 0):

d) If the consequences become are (1), then they get the equation below.
$$ r ^ {n-1} = b_1 \cdot r ^ {n-2} + ... + b_m \cdot r ^ {n- (m + 1)} $$
Since the consequences result (1), then it must also apply to $ x_n = r_1 + ... + r_m $ moeter (1).
If the consequences become (1), then they must also require (1) if multiplied and constantly on, as shown in the equation below.
$$ c_1 \cdot r ^ {n-1} = c_1 \cdot (b_1 \cdot r ^ {n-2} + ... + b_m \cdot r ^ {n- (m + 1)}) = c_1 \cdot b_1 \cdot r ^ {n-2} + ... + c_1 \cdot b_m \ cdot r ^ {n- (m + 1)} $$
Since the consequences supplement (1) with a constant multiplied by, it must also apply that $ x_n = c_1 \cdot r_1 + .... + c_m \cdot r_m $ (1).

[image]

any tips to help argue for this question